# Unable to Open SMTP Port (25, 587) on Vultr

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, postfix, smtp, dovecot

I'm using Vultr for Web Hosting and according to them they have unblocked all SMTP Ports (25, 465, 587, 2525). Now after setting up apache server and installing Postfix, Dovecot and SpamAssassin when I tested it by sending the mail I got this error:

```
Connection could not be established.
getaddrinfo for mail.domain.com failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

When I run nslookup against the domain I get a valid IP but when I run it against mail.domain.com I get this error message:

```
** server can't find mail.domain.com: SERVFAIL
```

I have allow both port 25 and 587 in the ufw. I checked the status of both port 25 and 587 using different technique that I found on the internet (nmap, netstat, iptables). These are the result:

[image]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how can I open port 25 and 587 so that I will be able to send and receive emails. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your DNS server for "mail.domain.com",
or whatever you are really using. fix that.

To see if the socket is working test using telnet or netcat to the IP address.

Comment: I used both `telnet` and `netcat` commands with the IP address for port 25 and 587. I get **Connection Refused** error.

I've **MX** entry for the domain in the DNS setting. I don't have any entry for `mail.domain.com`

Comment: I will remove all my DNS entries and reset them again. I hope that it works. BTW port `80, 443, 3306, 993, 995, and 22` are working fine. I'm only having problems with port `25 and 587`

Answer (score 0):

you must put a ticket to vultr support, because they block some ports to new accounts. look this, https://www.vultr.com/docs/what-ports-are-blocked/

they tell you use our VPS for a month and next create a ticket. that no warranty we review your case, but we will see your habitual use.